# How to auto login to GCP using gcloud cli?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automation, gcloud, terraform-provider-gcp

We have GCP account credentials(username/password). We have installed gcloud CLI on the Amazon Linux EC2 machine. We would like to create a script that would auto-login to the GCP account and do the below things sequentially using gcloud CLI.

- Login to the GCP account.
- Create Project and specify a meaningful project-id.
- Create a service account with a meaningful ID.
- Assign the owner role to the service account.
- Create and download a new JSON key.

Please help us to achieve this

Comment: You can use bash or python scripting.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. We would like to automate it via bash scripting only but we don't know the process. I have tried to find but no fate.

Comment: The first step is to read the documentation for the CLI and learn how to write commands for each step. If shell scripting is an issue, then learn that as well. However, a better solution is to use Terraform to provision resources.

Comment: There are several concerns with your strategy. 1) **Create a service account with a meaningful ID.** That requires permissions that should not be assigned to a VM. 2) **Assign the owner role to the service account** That role should not be assigned to a service account and should be used only in special cases. 3) I recommend getting some advice from someone that has strong knowledge of Google Cloud security and authorization.

Comment: I am guessing that you are trying to create project create automation for customers. You will need to increase your quotas to be able to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a Service Account not a User (username|password) for automation. The Service Account should be suitably permissioned so that it can create Projects and Service Accounts.

I was unable to find a source for this (but it used to be that?) Google monitors User Accounts for apparent use of automation (e.g. for bots) and these accounts may be disabled.

Comment: Plus user accounts are subject to reduced quota restrictions.

Comment: Hey, DazWilkin and John thanks for your suggestion. Actually, we are new to the GCP ecosystem that's why the query might sound naive. But yes, we are trying to automate the GKE infra provisioning through Terraform for 1 click deployment in any client account. We are currently using the SA JSON key in the template to authenticate, is this the right way? Also, We are following this shorturl.at/fjvP6 article to achieve full automation. From your points, it seems that we should have a SA pre-created and then execute the whole stuff based on that key authentication including the creation of the pro

Comment: It's going to be challenging for us to help you architect your solution via Stack overflow comments. I encourage you to read Google's documentation and work with your Google engineering liaisons. Yes, to the use Service Accounts. It seems challenging for you to invert a more common control flow in which the user (with credentials for a project) initiates deployment of resources into their project(s). This is the mechanism by which Google services are added to Projects and I assume the model that's used by partner solutions offered by Cloud Console.

Comment: If you follow the active approach, you may be able to use [Workfload Identity Federation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation) of AWS credentials instead of using Google Service Accounts.